# Can I edit the wp_post > post_content right before its inserted/updated?

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, wp-insert-post, wp-update-post, encryption

I would need to apply some sort of encryption on whatever gets inserted in the wp_post > post_content, so I was wondering if there is a way, either modifying the core (rather not), or using some filter or hook and function, where I could perform the encryption right before the content gets saved.

And then once called for by the frontend or backend, to apply an decryption, before the post_content gets actually used.

Thanks in advance to anyone with some advice on the matter!

Comment: you can hook on this action : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/

Comment: @mmm `save_post` is fired after post is inserted, so it's a little bit too late, I guess...

Comment: Have you tried `content_save_pre` filter? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre (I've never tried it, I just know it exists :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is possible, but it will be a little bit tricky and I would recommend a lot of testing after deploying this solution.

Disclaimer: I use `base64_encode` and `base64_decode` as cipher/decipher functions, but of course you can change them to whatever you like.

**First part** (encoding before post is stored in DB) is pretty easy:

```
function encrypt_post_content( $data, $postarr ) {
    $data['post_content'] = base64_encode( $data['post_content'] );
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'encrypt_post_content', 10, 2 );
```

**Second part** is a little bit trickier, because WordPress uses `raw` context in many places and if this context is used, then no filters are applied to post fields...

```
function decrypt_post_content( $content, $default_editor =false ) {
    return base64_decode( $content );
}
add_filter( 'the_editor_content', 'decrypt_post_content', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'decrypt_post_content', 1, 1 );
```

PS. It's a little bit sad that there is no easy possibility to modify post_content just after getting it from DB... :(

Comment: Thank you very much Krzysiek, I'll test it out and I will let you know :-)

Comment: It works like a magic! thank you! I just added different cryptation, but it seems to be like a ready to go solution.